# Android Studio - how to have it generate an interface's stubbed function(s)?

Tags: android

Since I've recently switched to A.S. I'm still getting accustomed to it, hence, this basic question...

I'll be coding a class that implements an interface

```
public class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {}
```

Now, Android Studio will detect that I haven't yet implements concrete functions for the interface. Great, just like Eclipse ! It'll show the message `class SomeClass must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method... etc`

However, the GUI doesn't show anything for me to click on so that the IDE will create stubbed functions for me; there's no icon and right-click also provides no intuitive direction to fix this. Eclipse provided solutions when I right-clicked, but A.S. doesn't seem as intuitive.

What to do to make A.S. implement stubbed functions for me ?

Comment: Alt-Enter is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your text cursor in the red squiggled area for the error. Move your mouse to the left edge of the line. Click the red lightbulb icon. Choose "Implement Methods" from the drop-down menu.

Or, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>.

Or, choose Code > Implement Methods from the main menu.

Comment: awesome! CTRL-I (a little bit difficult on the mac with one hand) works nicely even if I just have the mouse pointer over the code that is squiggled red. To get the red light bulb to show up I noticed that I have to put the cursor on somewhere in that line. Thanks.